# 1railstutorial.org 10.3.3 Pagination error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
>> User.all.class
=> Array
>> User.paginate(:page => 1).class
TypeError: can't convert nil into Array
```

not work, but

```
>> User.all.class
=> Array
>> User.all.paginate(:page => 1).class
=> WillPaginate::Collection
```

seems OK and

```
  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
```

this right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "will paginate" gem, this following code should work for you.

```
 def index
  @title = "All users"
  @users = User.paginate page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
 end
```